# How can you pack/minify css and js files in mod_perl?

Tags: perl, optimization, compression, pack

Is there a utility/module similar to pack in Java where you can compile all the css files  into one css file and all the js files into a one js file?

Comment: Related, but not fulfilling the requirements from the question: [Apache2::Filter::Minifier::CSS](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::Filter::Minifier::CSS), [Apache2::Filter::Minifier::JavaScript](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::Filter::Minifier::JavaScript), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909389/server-side-auto-minify. See also: [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you:
https://metacpan.org/module/Apache2::Response::FileMerge

Answer (score 2):

Two modules that look like they ought to do what you want (sorry I haven't personally used either):

- [JavaScript::Minifier](https://metacpan.org/module/JavaScript%3a%3aMinifier)
- [CSS::Minifier](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS%3a%3aMinifier)