# Is there a JS minifier server-side on Apache?

Tags: javascript, apache

I'm using mod-pagespeed for optimization.
I was wondering if something similar as a module could exist to minify files

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909389/server-side-auto-minify). But it's better to do these minifications offline as part of build process, so that you don't have to do it every time you serve that resource :)

Answer (score 0):

ModPagespeed with its different filters can do work for you. Please have a look at https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-minify